# Can a var = 2 things

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working with Unity for a while now and been scripting with C# a bit.

I'm working on a script that checks if selected target is a NPC or a Craft(station).

As the base of the script is calling upon many other scripts and variables, I don't want to duplicate all of the scripts in order to make the other kind of NPC which is , in my case, the Craft(station).

Let me explain in detail with examples now:

```
void UpdateNpcTrading(Player player) {
    // only if visible
    if (!npcTradingPanel.activeSelf) return;

    // npc trading
    if (player.target != null && player.target is Craft &&
        Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, player.target.transform.position) <= player.talkRange) {
        var npc = (Craft)player.target; // Here is the var I need to edit

        // items for sale            
        for (int i = 0; i < npcTradingContent.childCount; ++i) {
            var entry = npcTradingContent.GetChild(i).GetChild(0);

            // get the item
            if (i < npc.saleItems.Length) {
                var item = npc.saleItems[i];
```

There is more to it ( feel free to ask for it if needed )

So the line : `var npc = (Craft)player.target;` identifies npc as Craft because `player.Target = Craft`.
But I'd like to edit it so It checks if the `player.target = Craft` then, Set `var npc = Craft`
but if `player.target = Npc` , Set `var npc = Npc` instead.

Not sure if I make myself clear or not. Please feel free to ask for more details and I'll do my best.

Any help is most appreciated, Mike

EDIT :

Ok so I've scripted it like this. Still when I run in game it doesnt looks like it knows what to do.. ( But compilers doesnt show syntax error )

```
// npc trading
        if (player.target != null && player.target is Craft &&
            Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, player.target.transform.position) <= player.talkRange) {
            var npc = (Craft)player.target;

        }else if (player.target != null && player.target is Npc &&
                Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, player.target.transform.position) <= player.talkRange) {
                var npc = (Npc)player.target;

            // items for sale            
            for (int i = 0; i < npcTradingContent.childCount; ++i) {
                var entry = npcTradingContent.GetChild(i).GetChild(0);

                // get the item
                if (i < npc.saleItems.Length) {
                    var item = npc.saleItems[i];
```

Where am I wrong

Comment: When you are writing `var something = ...` the type determination is automatic. I think if you remove the explicit cast you will get what you are asking for. Just use `var npc = player.target;` and it should work. Please correct if I didn't understand your point.

Comment: A `var` can only have one type and that type has to be determined at compile time, not at runtime. If you need a variable that can represent a type of `Craft` and a type of `Npc` then you need it to be some common base type or some common interface that both classes implement.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is `if (player.target is Craft) { ... }`. I may not be understanding your needs, though.

Comment: +1 for common base type.  "Interactive Object" or something of that nature.  Then NPC and Craft can inherit this.

Comment: Is there a way I could use like : if (player.target != null && player.target is Craft &&
            Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, player.target.transform.position) <= player.talkRange) {
            var npc = (Craft)player.target; and else if (player.target != null && player.target is Npc &&
            Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, player.target.transform.position) <= player.talkRange) {
            var npc = (Npc)player.target;

Comment: In your first code the Craft(Station) has the for loop in it's if, in the edit the for loop is inside the if statement for the NPC, and the if for the Craft9Station) doesn''t have a for loop, is that intended?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are looking for the `is` operator.

```
if (player.target is Craft)
{
    var npc = (Craft)player.target;
    // do other 'Craft' logic here
}
else if (player.target is Npc)
{
    var npc = (Npc)player.target;
    // do other 'Npc' logic here
}
```

I'm assuming that `player.target` can either be an `Npc` or a `Craft`? If this is the case then they both inherit from whatever base type `player.target` is. You can check if it is either a `Craft` or `Npc` with the `is` operator before you cast.

Comment: Yeah this looks good. I'm new to C# , i'll try to write it like that, and i'll tell you if it works , thanks a lot

Comment: Although @jsmith answers the question, it's worth mentioning that type casting and conversions incur performance penalties so instead of saying if (player.target is Craft) { var npc = (Craft)player.target; .... } rather say var npc = player.target as Craft if(npc != null) { ... }